# Error in installing sweetviz in Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda3

When I am trying to install `sweetviz` for studying some data analysis for my data science studies it showing the below error.
Please help me to do analysis with installation of `sweetviz`.

```
!pip install sweetviz #This is the line of code i am using in Jupyter notebook.
```

The error is:

> Unable to create process using 'C:\Users\Win 10\anaconda3\python.exe
> "C:\Users\Win 10\anaconda3\Scripts\pip-script.py" install sweetviz

Comment: Have you tried `%pip install sweetviz` in the cell in your notebook? Windows tends to be tricky and so not guaranteed to help; however it is worth trying the current best practice installing, see [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/why-users-can-install-modules-from-pip-but-not-from-conda/10722/4?u=fomightez) for more about the newer magics command.

Comment: YES! Its worked.Thank you so much..

Comment: I should add that most times you can even leave off the `%` because most Jupyter these days has automagics enabled by default, and so it usually tries the magic command variation itself. That is not guaranteed though, and so it's good to know the full magic command. The thing to avoid for `pip install` and `conda install` is the exclamation point, as you found.

Answer (score -1):

Try writing
%%capture
!pip install sweetviz

i hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).